# Apache camel-apache kafka integration

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-camel

I am learning how to integrate kafka with apache camel and i encountered the following error.
Any help will be appreciated.I have a file created inside C:/inbox folder and want to consume the text in it using kafka consumer.I am using version 3.1.0 of apache camel.Below is my code

```
package com.javainuse;

import org.apache.camel.builder.RouteBuilder;

public class SimpleRouteBuilder extends RouteBuilder {

@Override
public void configure() throws Exception {

    String topicName = "test123";
    String kafkaServer = "kafka:localhost:9092";
    String zooKeeperHost = "zookeeperHost=localhost&zookeeperPort=2181";
    String serializerClass = "serializerClass=kafka.serializer.StringEncoder";
    String toKafka = "kafka:localhost:9092;kafka:test123?brokers=localhost:9092;zookeeperHost=localhost;zookeeperPort=2181;groupId=group1";

    from("file:C:/inbox?noop=true").to(toKafka);
}
}
```

And below is the error I am getting

````
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
org.apache.camel.FailedToStartRouteException: Failed to start route route1 because of Route(route1)[From[file:C:/inbox?noop=true] -> [To[kafka:loc...
    at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.BaseRouteService.warmUp(BaseRouteService.java:133)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.AbstractCamelContext.doWarmUpRoutes(AbstractCamelContext.java:3246)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.AbstractCamelContext.safelyStartRouteServices(AbstractCamelContext.java:3139)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.AbstractCamelContext.doStartOrResumeRoutes(AbstractCamelContext.java:2925)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.AbstractCamelContext.doStartCamel(AbstractCamelContext.java:2725)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.AbstractCamelContext.lambda$doStart$2(AbstractCamelContext.java:2527)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.AbstractCamelContext.doWithDefinedClassLoader(AbstractCamelContext.java:2544)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.AbstractCamelContext.doStart(AbstractCamelContext.java:2525)
    at org.apache.camel.support.service.ServiceSupport.start(ServiceSupport.java:121)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.AbstractCamelContext.start(AbstractCamelContext.java:2421)
    at com.javainuse.MainApp.main(MainApp.java:12)
Caused by: org.apache.camel.RuntimeCamelException: org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: Failed to construct kafka producer
    at org.apache.camel.RuntimeCamelException.wrapRuntimeCamelException(RuntimeCamelException.java:52)
    at org.apache.camel.support.ChildServiceSupport.start(ChildServiceSupport.java:67)
    at org.apache.camel.support.service.ServiceHelper.startService(ServiceHelper.java:70)
    at org.apache.camel.support.service.ServiceHelper.startService(ServiceHelper.java:87)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.channel.DefaultChannel.doStart(DefaultChannel.java:144)
    at org.apache.camel.support.service.ServiceSupport.start(ServiceSupport.java:121)
    at org.apache.camel.support.service.ServiceHelper.startService(ServiceHelper.java:70)
    at org.apache.camel.support.service.ServiceHelper.startService(ServiceHelper.java:73)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.doStart(Pipeline.java:154)
    at org.apache.camel.support.service.ServiceSupport.start(ServiceSupport.java:121)
    at org.apache.camel.support.service.ServiceHelper.startService(ServiceHelper.java:70)
    at org.apache.camel.support.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.doStart(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:78)
    at org.apache.camel.support.service.ServiceSupport.start(ServiceSupport.java:121)
    at org.apache.camel.support.service.ServiceHelper.startService(ServiceHelper.java:70)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.BaseRouteService.startChildService(BaseRouteService.java:339)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.BaseRouteService.doWarmUp(BaseRouteService.java:189)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.BaseRouteService.warmUp(BaseRouteService.java:131)
    ... 10 more
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: Failed to construct kafka producer
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.<init>(KafkaProducer.java:432)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.<init>(KafkaProducer.java:298)
    at org.apache.camel.component.kafka.KafkaProducer.doStart(KafkaProducer.java:119)
    at org.apache.camel.support.service.ServiceSupport.start(ServiceSupport.java:121)
    at org.apache.camel.support.service.ServiceHelper.startService(ServiceHelper.java:70)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.AbstractCamelContext.internalAddService(AbstractCamelContext.java:1455)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.AbstractCamelContext.addService(AbstractCamelContext.java:1391)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.SendProcessor.doStart(SendProcessor.java:240)
    at org.apache.camel.support.service.ServiceSupport.start(ServiceSupport.java:121)
    at org.apache.camel.support.service.ServiceHelper.startService(ServiceHelper.java:70)
    at org.apache.camel.support.service.ServiceHelper.startService(ServiceHelper.java:87)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.errorhandler.RedeliveryErrorHandler.doStart(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:1454)
    at org.apache.camel.support.ChildServiceSupport.start(ChildServiceSupport.java:60)
    ... 25 more
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.config.ConfigException: Invalid url in bootstrap.servers: localhost:9092;zookeeperHost=localhost;zookeeperPort=2181;groupId=group1
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.ClientUtils.parseAndValidateAddresses(ClientUtils.java:58)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.ClientUtils.parseAndValidateAddresses(ClientUtils.java:47)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.<init>(KafkaProducer.java:407)
    ... 37 more

Process finished with exit code 0```
````

Answer (score 0):

The error stacktrace says that your **Kafka consumer URI is invalid** (at the bottom of the stacktrace). And it is indeed.

The correct form is `kafka:[topicname]?[options]` (check [Camel-Kafka docs](https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/kafka-component.html))

So when I look at your URI it should probably be

```
kafka:test123?brokers=localhost:9092&groupId=group1
```

Your URI has the following problems:

- It contains 2 times `kafka:[topicname]` what is invalid
- One of the `kafka:[topicname]` is `kafka:[brokers]`, remove it
- Semicolons (`;`) instead of `&` to delimit options
- Zookeeper options for old versions of camel-kafka, remove them

---

By the way: The line `SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation` on top of your stacktrace says that you use SLF4J logging interface, but you have no implementation added to your project.

If you use Maven, you can add the following dependency to add the SLF4J API as well as [Logback](http://logback.qos.ch/) as implementation to your project.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
    <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
</dependency>
```